# Animation Nodes Delay of Cell Fractured Collection Matrix

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to make a simple animation in 2.8 by (mostly) following [This video by BLUE FOX](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8SMFucF-SC8)

However, I would like to make the cell fractured objects slowly return to their starting points, instead of an instant warp. I have played around with nodes and google for the last several hours, to no avail.

I have an image of the nodes I am using, as well as a gif of the current effect I wish to change - Any and all help is appreciated.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I think change the scale to 0.2 in 'offset matrix'
[image]